# How can I update an xml file periodically?

Tags: java, sql

Hy,
I have to make a query on a Facebook table witch will return xml information about number of likes and so on.I have to keep those info in database or in a xml file on the disc and every day at a certain hour i have to update those dates.
How can i make those updates at a certain time?
If the information is very large and i can't store in database,can i store it in a xml file?

Answer (score 3):

If the amount of data or its volume would prove troublesome for a database, you certainly won't benefit from using XML for storage! Quite the contrary. Find out if perhaps your database supports XML as a column type. If it does, it might supply XPath-based indexing and maybe even updates. If you get the info as XML, maybe some manner of bridging the XML to relational DB gap would be of use. Using EclipseLink for persistance would provide an excellent bridge in the form of using JAXB together with JPA.

As for scheduled updates, maybe try to find out if you always need all the info or just a subset. Even if you can't request partial data, maybe filtering out some stuff you don't need (like with an XSLT transform) could reduce memory footprint and processing time further down the line. Using JPA entities would certainly make synching and updates easier.